# How do I mount a DataDisk in Azure Batch while using ContainerConfiguration (Docker)?

Tags: docker, azure-batch

I would like to use Azure batch with Docker Containers, and also add data disks to have a bigger working space in each node.

1. Azure Batch DataDisk works same in batch nodes as in VMs. Which means I need to mount them. This can be automated by running [a script](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/shared_scripts/ubuntu/vm-disk-utils-0.1.sh) at startup.
2. If a drive is mounted on the vm, I can [mount that within the docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64763378/can-i-use-docker-volumes-in-container-based-azure-batch-pools) also.
   But how do I do (1) automatically, when I am using azure batch with container_settings. My initial commands will run inside the docker. How do I send the script to the VM before the docker is initialized?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to my own question. The initial commands don't run inside the docker, they run on the host vm. So, we format the disk at node start task, defined while creating the pool:

```
    mount_script = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure-Samples/compute-automation-configurations/master" \
                   "/prepare_vm_disks.sh "
    initial_commands = [f"wget {mount_script}",
                        "chmod 777 prepare_vm_disks.sh",
                        "./prepare_vm_disks.sh"]
    initial_command = "&&".join(initial_commands)
    initial_command = f'/bin/bash -c "{initial_command}"'
    start_task=batchmodels.StartTask(
            command_line=initial_command,
            wait_for_success=True,
            user_identity=batchmodels.UserIdentity(
                auto_user=batchmodels.AutoUserSpecification(
                    scope=batchmodels.AutoUserScope.pool,
                    elevation_level=batchmodels.ElevationLevel.admin))
```

And then `docker create` is run for each task separately. That is when the disk is mounted to the docker container:

```
        task_container_settings = batch.models.TaskContainerSettings(
            image_name=...,
            container_run_options="--mount type=bind,source=/datadisks/disk1,target=/data"
        )
        batch.models.TaskAddParameter(
            container_settings=task_container_settings,
            user_identity=batchmodels.UserIdentity(
                auto_user=batchmodels.AutoUserSpecification(
                    scope=batchmodels.AutoUserScope.pool,
                    elevation_level=batchmodels.ElevationLevel.admin)
            )
        )
```